# rename of file extensions recursively and delete old files (windows batch)

Tags: file, date, batch-file, rename

I'm trying to rename a large group of files from foobar.ext to foobar.bak, recursively, then delete the contents of a folder more than 3 months old.

I've read through numerous posts, but the syntax is eluding me, usually I just get a blank command line after running the batch file.

```
D:
CD\
FOR /R %%x IN (foobar.ext) DO ECHO ren "%%x" *.bak
CD \rvt_backup
FORFILES /D -90 /M *.rvt /C "cmd /c DEL @fname"
```

no files renamed, just a list of folder paths each followed by "The system cannot find the file specified."
Then a blank command line with no files deleted.

Comment: You need to clarify where exactly your files and folder are located...

Comment: You do "Echo rename", which means "show the rename command", instead of executing it. What happens when you drop the "echo" command?

Comment: @Kris As stated in the documentation (ss64) for `ren`. After `DO` clause and removing `echo` write `ren "%%x" "%~nx.bak"`. Probably, it should work fine.

Comment: I would recommend that you do not use the metavariable `%x` as `%~x` can be confused with e`x`tensions.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the documentation (ss64) for `ren`. Try this,

After `DO` clause, remove `echo` write `ren "%%x" "%~nx.bak"`.

Probably, it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers -- I tried the version suggested:

    FOR /R %%G IN (foobar.ext) DO ren "%%G" "%~nG.bak"

And got this response:

> The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
> substitution is invalid: %~nG.bak" 
> 
> For valid formats type CALL /? or FOR /? The syntax of the command is
> incorrect.

So I've tried this instead:

    FOR /R %%G IN (foobar.ext) DO ren "%%G" "%%~nG.bak"

Comment: It works albeit lists every folder without that file with an error (there are hundreds with and without, so this output tends to be quite messy):

> ren "D:\foldernames\subfolders\foobar.ext" "foobar.bak" The system
> cannot find the file specified
Any idea if the batch output can ignore the folders without those files ?